# Solutions for blazing fast image retrieval

Tags: image, amazon-s3, cloud, hosting

I am creating a meme type website where a user can upload an image, enter some text on the image and we will host it. Access to the images needs to be as fast as possible.

Is there a third party solution that will allow me to host my images? I've tried Amazon S3 but seem to be having issues when uploading 100's of files at a time. I've read that S3 isn't the ideal solution for image hosting of this nature. And Cloudfront doesn't allow pushing (to my knowledge).

Are there any third party services that allow pushing images?

Comment: I wonder what is the use case which is not sufficed S3. S3 is meant for scalability, can you provide the link where it says that S3 is not the ideal solutions?

Comment: You may need to read some more.  You don't push to CloudFront, it pulls on demand from the origin server (S3).  There is no reason that comes to mind why you would have "issues" loading hundreds of files "at a time," depending on how "at a time" is defined.  You may want to focus on that issue, as it should be resolvable.  You need to retry on "Slow Down" errors, if that's what you are seeing.   S3 will scale itself up beyond 100 `PUT` req/sec to meet your workload, but it isn't instantaneous on a bucket that has never seen heavy traffic.  Also, product/service recommendations are off-topic.